# iOS - Oh geez. Your build failed. Click the "Log" button above to view the compile log

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap-cli

I am facing some error while compiling my PhoneGapp iOS App.
Can Any One Help Me?

Error:-
Oh geez. Your build failed. Click the "Log" button above to view the compile log. If you need help diagnosing the issue, you can post to the support forum with your App ID (please do a search first).

Comment: Nobody can help you. Why do you not post the "Log" here? Besides, the tags maybe abusing?

Comment: This is the 1st time I am posting. I don't know how it works. Plz remove the badge

Comment: "Click the "Log" button above to view the compile log.". Then click the `Log` button, and look for the exact error. Try to search that error and solve by yourself, then post those one you can't solve.

Comment: now I am fixed this issue